# Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:deploy ... InstallException: TimeoutException

Tags: android, exception, maven

I have been trying to convert my Android project to maven and after some issues I am struggling to deploy.  I can clean and install but when it comes to the deploy I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:deploy (default-cli) on project mega: Uninstall of org.jointsecurityarea.android.mega failed. InstallException: TimeoutException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:deploy (default-cli) on project mega: Uninstall of org.jointsecurityarea.android.mega failed.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Uninstall of org.jointsecurityarea.android.mega failed.
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo$2.doWithDevice(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:806)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.doWithDevices(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:715)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.undeployApk(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:792)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.undeployApk(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:776)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.deployApk(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:600)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.deployBuiltApk(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:670)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.standalonemojos.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:57)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.uninstallPackage(Device.java:687)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo$2.doWithDevice(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:798)
... 27 more
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:648)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.readAdbResponse(AdbHelper.java:216)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:378)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:372)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.uninstallPackage(Device.java:684)
... 28 more
```

I am attempting to run this from the command line, not using the m2e plugin.  Also, here is my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.jointsecurityarea</groupId>
<artifactId>mega</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>Mega</name>

<properties>
    <platform.version>4.0.1.2</platform.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>17</platform>
                    <path>C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk</path>
                </sdk>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                <device>usb</device>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[3.2.0,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am brand new to Maven.  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What is org.jointsecurityarea.android.mega ?

Comment: Where is your [distributionManagement section](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management)? Where do you want to deploy?

Comment: So all I am trying to do is to android:deploy to my connected Android device.  I don't think I need to set the distributionManagement section for this action.   I believe it is handled in the configuration tag of the android-maven-plugin.